# How to manipulate an ActiveRecord::Relation result and filter it without query to the database again

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I want to retrieve records form table, initialize some fields, and then update data on memory (not saving to database) after some filter. But this second filter makes a new query to the database, so I can't initialize these fields.

How can I solve this issue?

```
res=where(code: 0)          # (1) retrieve objects from db, as a template
res.each{|r| r.amount=10}    # (2) change amount field with 10 in res
```

**Here I expect 10+2 but the result is 0+2:** because next line executes query on database, so line (2) it has no effect

```
 res.where("caconana='1221").first.amount+= 2
```

Possible answer: Is there a better solution than convert 'res' to an array?

```
res=where(code: 0).to_a
res.each{|r| r.amount=10}
i=res.find_index{|r| r.caconana=='1221'}
res[i]+=2
```

Thanks to PSKocit I have the solution: **find method does not execute query to database**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That each method call on res will cause all the matching ActiveRecords object to be fully constructed anyway. So if you do want them constructed, you might as well use the caconana attributes that got loaded:

```
res.each {|r| r.amount = 10 }
res.find {|r| r.caconana == 1221 }.amount+=2
```

(Then you'd need to `save` each record to have that committed to the database.)

You can avoid some ActiveRecord object construction with:

```
where(code: 0).update_all(amount: 10) #One query to the database, no AR objects constructed in memory
```

Then for the incrementing (this is with AR object construction, but it's just for one record)

```
obj = where(code: 0).where(caconana: 1221).limit(1).first
obj.amount+=2
#obj.save!
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I do not want to save these changes to the database. But your first solution is what i was looking for: ´find´ method does not execute query to database, ´where´ method yes. Thanks you. Some times I have trouble finding specific  documentation, about ´find´ method for example ..:(